# vespa deploy --wait 300 app-1-getting-started get error-code "METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED"

Tags: vespa

When I follow this article to practice vepsa
https://docs.vespa.ai/en/tutorials/news-1-getting-started.html

when i do this step
vespa deploy --wait 300 app-1-getting-started

### i got this error

```
{
    "error-code": "METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED",
    "message": "Method 'POST' is not supported"
}
```

why and how can i fix this error ?

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to reproduce, I just ran through the steps. I suggest you submit an issue at https://github.com/vespa-engine/vespa/issues with your environment and also include vespa.log for the Vespa Team to have a look

Comment: sorry, i pull vespaengine/vespa:7.571.25 version before, so i decide to delete images, and pull latest version again, and the problem is disappear !

Comment: even if i delete the latest version and pull 7.571.25 version, now it can be deployed OK !

Comment: I am unable to reproduce too !    sorry about this, the problem is no longer exist, thank you for answer.

Answer (score 1):

Vespa deploys to `http://localhost:19071/` and if the service running on that port is not the Vespa configuration service, but a different HTTP server that returns 405, this might explain the behavior you observe. The tutorial starts the Vespa container image using 3 port bindings

- 8080:8080 is the Vespa container (data plane, read and write)
- 19071:19071 is the Vespa configuration service which accepts app package (control plane)

```
docker run -m 10G --detach --name vespa --hostname vespa-tutorial \
  --publish 8080:8080 --publish 19071:19071 --publish 19092:19092 \
  vespaengine/vespa
```